# локальный сервер для фронтенда

Tags: javascript, three.js, faq

## Настройка Chrome для three.js

Друзья, настраиваю хром в соответствии с [документацией](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally), чтобы могли отображаться локальные изображения.

Что сделано не так, исходя из картинки? Не отображает...

Заранее спасибо [image: Снимок]

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb я рекомендую попробовать плагин для хрома

Comment: Лучше попробовать поднять простенький локальный сервер. В том разделе ("How to run things locally") написано про то, как это сделать.

Comment: @prisoner849 большое спасибо, посмотрю про Node.js тем более он на слуху.

Comment: @qwabra большое спасибо, установила, но что дальше? от простого запуска не накладывается локалка.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## локальный сервер для фронтенда

1. хороший вариант
2. простой

### 2. простой

установить плагин (Web Server for Chrome) для браузера chrome
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb

запустить его можно отсюда `chrome://apps` , после этого можно будет  зафиксировать на панели задач

кнопка `CHOOSE FOLDER` = выбери папку (та папка где лежит html/js )
под ней ползунок - включить, выключить сервер

ниже ссылки на страничку

[image: плагин Web Server for Chrome]

### 1. хороший вариант

установить `nodejs` https://nodejs.org/en/download/
установить сам сервер `npm i -g reload`

`npm` - пакетный менеджер
`i` - установить
`-g` - глобально (для всей системы)

затем открыть консоль и перейти в желаемую папку с файлом index.html
и выполнить команду `reload`

преимущества `reload` - при изменении кода внутри js/html файлов все открытые страницы на всех устройствах во всех браузерах сами обновляются

Comment: большое спасибо

Comment: c web-сервером 200ок все получилось, большое спасибо. можете только сказать, как его на панели задач закрепить. Не нахожу, и гугл не выдает....

Comment: 1. какая у вас операционная система  2. предположу: когда запускаете 200ок он появляется на панели задач, отдельным значком, как тот же хром и если это так - то щелкаете по нему(значку 200ок) правой кнопкой мыши и выбираете в выпадающем меню что-то вроде `закрепить`

Comment: и ещё, я смотрю вы не ставите галочку у ответов, ознакомьтесь пожалуйста с этим разделом справки https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: 7, на нет буке 8

Comment: хорошо, спасибо, я относительно недавно на этом форуме)